# How to define interface for class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have to specify all actions in interface whitch should be realized in class.

I transfered to TypeScript from PHP.

Creating interfaces in PHP is very easy:

```
interface iTemplate
{
    public function move($name, $var);

}
```

Class is:

```
Class Mover inmpelments iTemplate {
    function move($name, $var){}
}
```

How to do that in TypeScript? For example, I have class User, that can:

```
edit profile
see users
etc
```

Comment: The syntax is similar *but* I recommend you start with a tutorial or a book or the [typescript web site](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html) which is very helpful. That's better than asking a question on SO for every syntax nuance you are going to encounter programming in a new language.

Comment: I have found interface only for properties: not for function: `interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface MyInterface {
    editProfile(profileId: number): void;
    seeUsers(): object[];
    etc: string;
}

class MyImplementation implements MyInterface{
    editProfile(profileId: number): void {
        throw 'todo';
    }

    seeUsers(): object[] {
        throw 'todo';
    }

    readonly etc = 'something else'; 
}
```